# php script is not uploading image to specified folder

Tags: php, html, image, forms, image-uploading

although I know that is has been everywhere as a question, I can't find the reason it doesn't work:

I have gathered the code below to achieve image uploading to my site:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="insert.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and the insert.php is:

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("/httpdocs/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "/httpdocs/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "/httpdocs/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
     echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Well,the success messages are displayed correctly. However, no file is uploaded to the specified folder.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Check if move_uploaded_file() returns TRUE. You probably don't have write permissions or something.

Comment: `move_uploaded_file` returns true or false depending on success or not. You should be checking it when using it.

Comment: And make sure you have error reporting enabled. If it fails, it should display the reason.

Comment: Are you trying to write to an `httpdocs` folder at the *root* of the file system?  There's a good chance that's not correct.

Comment: You should check for `$_FILES["file"]["error"]` before doing **anything else**

Comment: try using an absolute path

Comment: Run the script from your root, create a folder called `uploads` then change all `/httpdocs/` to `uploads/` without the opening `/` and it should theoretically work. Another thing to mention is that, your script is not testing for upper-case extensions, so make sure that the file you test with, is `.jpg` and not `.JPG` etc.

Comment: Surrounding the end function with strtolower() may work for that.

Comment: I've lost count of the number of times this W3Schools example is used by users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the script from your root, create a folder called `uploads` then change all instances of `/httpdocs/` to `uploads/` (as I did below) without the opening `/` and it should (*theoretically*) work, as it did for me.

A few things to note is to make sure that this `< 20000` is increased if your file is less than 20,000 bytes. If the file you attempt to use to upload is higher than this number, then the script will throw an error of `Invalid file`

Make sure the folder is writeable e.g.: `0755` or `0777` (in my case it's 0755)

This has been tested on my own server using `uploads` as my uploading folder.

Plus as [Nikolay states in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20052020/1415724), you may want to check that also.

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000) // <= you may have to increase this value
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
     echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Comment: somehow it worked! probably I had wrong folders for the file transfer, anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're very much welcome @PanosVakalopoulos relative paths work better. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If everything with folder paths is correct, you should check for the limit of the file uploading, for example in .htaccess:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
```

or in pnp.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 10M
```

Default limit is 2048KB.

Answer (score 0):

Determine your root folder `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` to see if php can access the folder or is adding the file to right folder otherwise everything looks pretty fine.

Answer (score 0):

your specified address is incorrect !

use address like `c:/wamp/www/site/httpdocs/` **not** `http://site/httpdocs/`

if on Linux check writing permission for the folder.

Answer (score 0):

this was 100% and tested code 
addimage1 is name of files input type
postimages is an folder
and filed moved in postimages folder successfully

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["addimage1"]["tmp_name"],
      "postimages/" . $_FILES["addimage1"]["name"]);

Comment: Could You please add a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: <?php
include('connect.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

echo $addtitle=$_POST['addtitle'];
               ;
 
$image1=$_FILES['addimage1']['name'];

 $image_tmp=$_FILES['addimage1']['tmp_name'];

 
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["addimage1"]["tmp_name"],
      "postimages/" . $_FILES["addimage1"]["name"]);

"postimages=is folder name in Htdoc folder/root folder

use and array functinon and store all value

Answer (score -1):

```
if you have try  image upload in php but not uplaod  

 if you are working on cpanel then 
    your image folder must be change permission from 755 to 777
    its work for me

<?php  
$target_path = "upload/";  
$target_path = $target_path.basename( $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);   

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {  
    echo "File uploaded successfully!";  
} else{  
    echo "Sorry, file not uploaded, please try again!";  
}  
?> 

if this helpful for you give a thumbs up
```